# Why do some ssh sessions offer autocomplete and some not?

Tags: ssh, terminal

Very newbie question!

I'm sshing to two different servers, both part of the same Amazon AWS cluster. They're not run by me.

On one ssh session, the terminal lets me autocomplete. On the other session, it doesn't - I wish it did.

Why is this - is it an option set by the server administrator?

And can I do anything about it?

thanks!

Answer (score 19):

This isn't really a programming question, but it has to do with your shell.  You can try starting the `bash` shell (by typing `bash` at the prompt) and see if you can autocomplete.

If that works you can use `which bash` to verify it's location and then `chsh -s /bin/bash` to set your shell permanently.

A list of available shells can also be found in `/etc/shells`.

Comment: I can't change my shell for some reason. Is there way to do it as root? `You may not change the shell for 'counterstrike'.`

Answer (score 4):

It is a combination of the shell that is being used in your ssh session as well as it's configuration.

While your shell may support autocompletion it may not be configured for it. If you're using the bash shell, you can edit your local .bashrc file for the following to provide autocomplete.

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: The bash completion package is only needed for more advanced completion of things like command line options, server names, VCS repository directories, ... . Completion of commands, directories, file names, variables and user names works without it.

Answer (score 3):

Copied from [my own answer on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp):

It seems that specifically in Ubuntu [the entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are hashed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/42382), so SSH completion cannot read them. This is a feature, not a bug. Even by adding `HashKnownHosts no` to `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I was unable to prevent the host hashing.

However, the hosts that I am interested in are also found in `~/.ssh/config`. Here is a script for Bash Completion that reads the entries from that file:

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config | awk '{print $2}')

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

Put that script in `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` and then source it with the following command:

```
$ . /etc/bash_completion.d/ssh
```

I found [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) invaluable and I would not have been able to script this without it. Thank you [Steve Kemp](http://www.steve.org.uk/)  for writing that terrific guide!

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it could also be an issue that ssh hashes the hostnames in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

most installations I know use ~/.ssh/known_hosts as source for the list of available hosts for completion but some systems also started to set "HashKnownHosts yes", which prohibits using known_hosts as a source....

if your known hosts lines start with something like

```
|1|BWO5qDxk/cFH0wa05JLdHn+j6xQ=|rXQvIxh5cDD3C4
```

then hashing is activated.